# Power BI How to edit data source connection SQL Statement

Tags: powerbi

Is there a way to edit the SQL Server Database Advanced options SQL statement? (see below). I tried to edit it through Data source settings> Change Source, but the SQL statement box is greyed out. Note that i have 2 data sources 1.) Import table 2.) SQL statement that i need to modify.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click `Transform data` to open Power Query Editor:

[image]

In the list of queries in the left panel, select the query that you want to modify:

[image]

Double click the `Source` step in the list of applied steps in the right panel:

[image]

This will open the same dialog and you will be able to modify it:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!